# AngularJs $resource.save returning 404 error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, post, angular-resource

I am getting a 404 error while trying to create a new JSON file locally.

Here is my service:

```html
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function($resource){
    var resource = $resource('/data/event/:id', {id:'@id'});


  return {
        getEvent: function() {
           //return $http({method: 'GET', url:'/data/event/1'});
            //return $resource('/data/event/:id', {id:'@id'}).get({id:1});
            return resource.get({id:1});
        },
        save: function(event) {
            event.id = 999;
            return resource.save(event);
        }
  }
});
```

The web.server js code is as below:

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var events = require('./eventsController');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var app = express();

var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(rootPath + '/app'));

app.get('/data/event/:id', events.get);
app.post('/data/event:id', events.save);


app.listen(8000);
console.log('Listening on port 8000...');
```

The get function works perfectly fine, but the post always throws a 404 error.

See a screenshot below:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Missing a `/` in app.post route

Comment: Thank you.. it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, your Express server routes are bad defined.

So when trying to POST data on `/data/event/999`, no route is defined for.

```
app.get('/data/event/:id', events.get);
app.post('/data/event/:id', events.save); // You forgot '/' here
```

Comment: Thank you Zooly .. :) It works now.. I should have noticed it in the first place !

Comment: Nice, little miss! :P